# Bot does not work with one-to-one chat messages in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

We created a Custom App with Azure Bot that catches input from users (with RSC and without mentioning) and returns an Adaptive Card. The bot works well in Channels but it does not work in one to one chats. We also debugged the Bot and we do not get a hit when a user types in a chat but we do get a hit when the message is posted in a channel.

We did extend the app permissions by going into Teams Admin Center -> Mange Apps -> Clicked the App -> Permissions -> Review and approved the permissions. Then assigned the app to the proper users for testing.

Nothing seems to be working.

This is the manifest of the app.

[image]

We also created an App Registration for the Bot in Azure and added these API Permissions.

[image]

Then in Teams Admin Center we consented to all these permissions as your reply indicated. Still, the Bot receives only messages posted in Channels and not between users on one-to-one chats.

[image]

Comment: When you check in the Azure Bot registration, in the Azure portal, does the test chat work? Also, under the "Channels" section on that page, does it list any error under the Teams channel? Are you 100% sure your Azure App Id and Azure App Secret are registered properly in your running application?

Comment: Incidentally, NONE of the Graph or RSC permissions are needed to get this work

Comment: The test chat works. The Teams channel under Azure Bot shows "Healthy". Also inside Teams when you try the App inside a Channel it works. It does not work inside a one-to-one chat.

Comment: And the only "symptom" you're seeing is that the bot doesn't receive the message? It's for sure the same bot, just installed into the different scope?

Comment: What happens if you click the option in the Azure portal, to load the bot chat into Teams? There's an option to "Open in Teams" - it basically starts a chat, connected to the Bot's Azure Application ID directly

Comment: It opens up the Bot in Teams. When I text it, it works. Then I move to text to a user in a one-to-one chat and nothing.

Comment: "When I text it, it works" - that *sounds* like the bot is working fine...Can you elaborate what this means: "Then I move to text to a user in a one-to-one chat and nothing."

Comment: To better explain the context - Our Bot does the following: When a user types in a message that contains "#" we check if it has numeric values after it. If it does, the Bot looks for an order # and returns an adaptive card of the order. 1) When you write #12345 inside a Channel window, the bot returns the card. Without mentioning the bot as RCS permissions are set. 2) When you do the same in the bot window it also works. 3) Now if you try to do the same in a chat window between two users it does not work. The bot returns nothing. We checked the endpoint it does not get triggered.

Comment: ahh ok, this helps a lot to work out what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments history in the OP, it's clear the main challenge is in a 'group chat' scenario - in that specific case, the bot isn't receiving the message. For this, see the following doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/channel-and-group-conversations?tabs=dotnet

Specifically:

> Bots in a group or channel only receive messages when they're mentioned @botname. They don't receive any other messages sent to the conversation. The bot must be @mentioned directly. Your bot doesn't receive a message when the team or channel is mentioned, or when someone replies to a message from your bot without @mentioning it.

The "Note" section just below this is important as well though:

> RSC for all chat messages is available only in public developer preview.

and also

> Using resource-specific consent (RSC), bots can receive all channel messages in teams that it's installed in without being @mentioned. For more information, see receive all channel messages with RSC.

Comment: So basically its not yet supported in any type of chat.  Their documentation is so bad and misleading. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Well it's not supported in "group" chat, to be clear, but yeah seems like not yet. At least it's being worked on :-)