# I have problems with using Azure Bot in Personal Chat in Microsoft Teams

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I developed Azure Bot with Bot Framework SDK on C#.
I configured and installed to Microsoft Teams.
I see the Bot is working.
My Bot should parse any message and should to find expression like #{0123456789} . It is working for Teams and sending message to Bot Channel.
But isn't working for Personal Chat. I can write with Bot Name in Private Channel: @BotName #123455
But if I write just #123455 then It isn't working. Teams doesn't send a Request to Azure Bot without BotName in private message ((
I tried any permissions for Application, but I can't find any solution.

I want to get my Azure Bot in Teams will be to parse  some messages without mentioning the  Botname.

I used this function

```
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
         
var activity = turnContext.Activity;
          var submitActionData = turnContext.Activity.Value as JObject;
            string action = null;
            if (submitActionData != null)
            {
                action = submitActionData["action"]?.ToString();
            }
                    var text = activity.Text.Trim().ToLower();
                    Regex regex = new Regex(@"#(\d+)");
                    MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(text);
                    if (matches.Count > 0)
                    {
                        List<string> identifiers = new List<string>();
                        foreach (Match match in matches)
                        {
                            identifiers.Add(match.Value.Replace("#", ""));
                        }
                        await FetchDataAndSendAdaptiveCardAsync(turnContext, identifiers, cancellationToken);
                    }
        }
```

Comment: I added the code.. But it doesn't make sense, because when I debugged I saw that I didn't any Request from Microsoft Teams for my case.

Comment: Please see this other answer I posted a few minutes ago and check if any of the comments or answer itself are relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78136290/bot-does-not-work-with-one-to-one-chat-messages-in-microsoft-teams?noredirect=1#comment137769562_78136290

Comment: Based on that, please update your answer with some of the additional info I discussed with the other person, that will help give more context for your question.